# Q# AggregateException could not be found

Tags: c#, error-handling, exception, quantum-computing, q#

After trying out this code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-simulatorsandmachines?view=qsharp-preview

```
try
{
    using (var sim = new QuantumSimulator())
    {
        /// call your operations here...
    }
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    // Unwrap AggregateException to get the message from Q# fail statement.
    // Go through all inner exceptions.
    foreach (Exception inner in e.InnerExceptions)
    {
        // If the exception of type ExecutionFailException
        if (inner is ExecutionFailException failException)
        {
            // Print the message it contains
            Console.WriteLine($" {failException.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Driver.cs(29,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AggregateException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/tinkidinki/Quantum/Bell/Bell.csproj]
Driver.cs(33,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Exception' could not be found (are you missing a using directiveor an assembly reference?) [/home/tinkidinki/Quantum/Bell/Bell.csproj]
Driver.cs(38,25): error CS0103: The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context [/home/tinkidinki/Quantum/Bell/Bell.csproj]

The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: FYI: There is a QC Q&A - https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you share your whole C# code? Given that the error messages mention even `Console`, looks like you're missing a `using System` in your C# code.